# Jackson circular dependency just through depth and not through both depth and breadth

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I have a class User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Car> cars;

    ...

}
```

And a class Car:

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    ...
```

I have a class Car that has a User and a User can have multiple cars.

The problem is:

When returning a list of Cars imagine car A and B.

Car A has User 1 and Car B has user 1 also.

Pseudo json serialization from the list:

```
Car A {
  User 1 {
   id: 1
   Cars: {
    Car A: {
     User 1 {
      id: 1 just shows id 1 - correct in my way of thinking because it already looked into a user 1 and so here it needs to stop the circular dependency.
     }
    }
   }
  }
}
Car B {
  User 1 {
   id: 1 here in my way of thinking it should print the full user because in this level it didnt find one user on top but it seems it takes into consideration the first element of the list (car A) where it already found a User 1? Why? 
  }
}
```

I would expect car B to also have the full user.

It seems jackson serialization works both in depth and in breadth.

And I would expect that it would work just in depth.

So basically since user 1 was already visited when returning the first Car (Car A) in the second one (breadth) it just shows the user 1 id in the Car B.

And I would expect that jackson would start again the circular dependency inspection when it jumps to car B.

How can I achieve that? Is it possible to configure jackson to just perform the circular dependency inspection in depth and not in breadth?

Thank you in advance for your help.

----- WORKING EXAMPLE CODE -----

```
package com.guds.test;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class test {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        User user1 = new User(1, "username 1");
        User user2 = new User(2, "username 2");
        Car car1 = new Car(1, "car 1", user1);
        Car car2 = new Car(2, "car 2", user1);
        Car car3 = new Car(3, "car 3", user2);
        Car car4 = new Car(4, "car 4", user2);

        user1.addGud(car1);
        user1.addGud(car2);

        user2.addGud(car3);
        user2.addGud(car4);

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(user1);
        users.add(user2);

        List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
        cars.add(car1);
        cars.add(car2);

        ObjectMapper om1 = new ObjectMapper();
        String json1 = null;
        try {
            json1 = om1.writeValueAsString(cars);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(json1);

        ObjectMapper om2 = new ObjectMapper();
        String json2 = null;
        try {
            json2 = om2.writeValueAsString(users);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(json2);

    }
}
```

CLASS CAR:

```
package com.guds.test;


public class Car {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    private User user;

    public Car(int id, String name, User user) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

CLASS USER:

```
package com.guds.test;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    List<Car> cars;

    public User(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.cars = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addCar(Car car) {
        this.cars.add(car);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In the first line of output in this program you can see what happens when you serialize the list of cars.

Comment: How do you get this json output? from list.toString()? or another way?

Comment: When I return a list of Car objects in the Car controller.

Comment: Is that really what you get when you log the whole list or? try to do user.getCars() when you are on CarB an tell us what happen please.

Comment: I added a working code example in the question so you can run it yourself and see the json string output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forgot to answer my own question. I already found a solution.

The simple way is to use @JsonIgnoreProperties.

I needed to change my classes:

```
package com.guds.test;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("user")
    List<Car> cars;

    public User(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.cars = new ArrayList<>();
    }

}

package com.guds.test;


public class Car {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("cars")
    private User user;

    public Car(int id, String name, User user) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

So in the case of the User class, when Jackson starts serializing it all the user properties are serialized and also the list of cars and the Car objects in themselves are serialized but since we say to ignore the property user when Jackson serializes the Car object it will not try to serialize the User inside the Car object.

In that way we break the cycle.

The same happens if you start the serialization from the Car objects.

Instead of what happens when using the @JsonIdentityInfo annotation we get all the information about the User and all the information of its Cars (except the User, but the info about the user we already have so...) even if they already appeared in the serialization process.

Hope it helps.